# I don't get it why the Second Borel Cantelli Lemma here will get me to this conclusion, I don't see the link

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

$Let\:\left(d_1\left(w\right),...\right)\:be\:a\:sequence\:for\:which\:d_{n\:}\left(w\right)=1\:obverse\:and\:d_n\left(w\right)=0\:reverse,\:let\:A_n=\left\{d_n\left(w\right)=1\right\},\:P\left(A_n\right)=\frac{1}{2}.\:Why,\:according\:to\:second\:Borel-Cantelli\:Lemma,\:the\:probability\:for\:\infty \:many\:occurring\:1\:is\:equal\:to\:100\%?$

Comment: It will be $1$ if events $A_n$  are independent for example (in the most standard version). There are generalisations, for example pairwise independence of $A_n$ is sufficient. But you need to assume something, because taking $d=d_n$ for every $n$, then $A_1=A_2=..$ and $\mathbb P( \infty A_n occurs ) = \mathbb P(A_1) = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: They are independent, as it's throwing a coin. I just don't get why $P\left(limsup_n\:A_n\right)=1$, I mean $limsup_n\:A_n$ is equal to $A_{\infty }$ here and this means that the infinite-position of this sequence is equal to 1, and that it doesn't have to mean that there are infinitely many 1s here, it can also be 0,.........,0,1 (at this "infinite place in the sequence") and thus there is only one 1 in this sequence just to name an example (so why should the probability of 1 occuring inifnitely many times be equal to 100%?)

Comment: @Student  What is $A_\infty$? What is an “infinite place in the sequence”? $\limsup_n A_n$ is exactly the event that infinitely many of the $A_n$ occur... that’s (a colloquial phrasing of) its definition.

Comment: "limsup is exactly the event that infinitely many of the  occur" Why? Limsup is by definition (A1 u A2 u A3 u ....) n (A2 u A3 u ....) n (A3 u .....)  which will be equal to the "last element of this infinite sequence" (thats _∞)

Comment: There is no such thing as the last element of an infinite sentence, quote marks or not. $A\cup B$ is the event that at least one of the events occur. $A\cap B$ is the event that both occur. In other words, union means “or” and intersection means “and”. So that nested union and intersection means that for every tail sequence $A_n, A_{n+1},\ldots,$ no matter how big $n$ is, has at least one of its events happen.

Comment: Ah, so I have to understand it as (A1 u A2 u A3...) as "at least one of those will happen" and  (A1 u A2 u A3...) n (A2 u A3 u ...) as "at least one of those from the left union will happen AND at least one of those from the right union will happen"? Because I understood it in form of sets, like. (A u B u C) n (B u C) n C = C thus the "last element is what will be left over". And because ""at least one of those events will happen" always and we have an infinite series we will always have infinitely many 1s in our sequence?

Comment: Well, it *is* sets. I think you just are extrapolating the case of finite sequences of sets to infinite sequences in a way that is unwarranted. (An event $A$ “happens” is just saying that $\omega\in A$. So a more mathematical way of putting it would be $x\in \limsup_nA_n$ iff $x$ is in infinitely many of the $A_n$.)

Comment: So because this is an infinite series my way of thinking that "what should be left over should be the last element of an infinite series" is wrong? But what if An = [0,1/n], shouldn't A_infinity be simply {0}? (as 1/infinity = 0)? And thus (A1 u A2 u A3 u ....) n (A2 u A3 u ....) n (A3 u .....) = {0}?